# Code works in Terminal, but not when in a script

Tags: command-line, bash

I have:
`This is my zip file.zip`  in path `$dec`

If I manually copy this code over to the terminal window, I get the correct output.

But, if I take the same exact code and put it into a .sh file and execute it with `set -x`,  I get this:

```
++ ls ''
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
```

Here is the code I'm using...

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
for k in $(ls "$dec"); do
echo $k
if [[ "$k" == "" ]];
then
echo -e "Nothing Here\n"
elif [[ "$k" =~ \.(doc|txt)$ ]];
then
   echo "Document"  
elif [[ "$k" =~ ".zip" ]];
then
    echo -e "ZIP"

    fi
done
```

Does anyone see why it will run when I manually copy it, but not when I execute it?

`$dec` is already defined.  I just left it out of this partial script.

```
~/Scripts/mypath$ echo $dec
/home/adam/Scripts/mypath/archived
```

Comment: you should set the `$dec` to your zip file path in your script too. dec='/path/to/zip'

Comment: May be try asking this on the Linux Unix stack or programming

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(ls $dec) in line 3 or am i completely wrong?

Comment: @KasiyA -- $dec is defined.  Also IFS is set to new line to accommodate spaces in file names.  @ Nikoc.  LS is where my script hangs, but as I said, it works fine when I copy it into terminal.

Comment: Sorry,  its not quoted in this specific script, but its quoted in the real script.  Ive stripped and cleaned this particular section of code and isolated it as this is what im having issues with.

Comment: By the way, don't do `for f in $(ls $dec)`. Use: `for f in "$dec"/*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$dec` has no value, you're doing `ls ""`. Try it and you'll see you get the same error message. Note `ls ""` is NOT the same as `ls` (without arguments). Check your script to see why `$dec` is not defined.

If, as you say, `$dec` is defined before you run the script, you probably need to export it so it's known to scripts you run.

```
export dec
./script.sh
```

Read this for more information on `export`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411455/what-does-export-do-in-shell-programming

Comment: You are correct, that is really strange.  I guess since I'm just testing line by line, I got to that section and it didn't recognize the $dec... but it does everywhere else, so that's kind of strange.  I'm baffled by this but thank you for your help.